# Change background fill of cells in LibreOffice worksheet containing specific text

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

How can I change the background fill of all the cells of a LibreOffice spreadsheet worksheet that contain a specified text?

In Excel that could be done by configuring the settings in the find and replace dialog.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to change the colour of the background of the cells dependant on the contents as in "conditional formatting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, in LibreOffice / OpenOffice Calc, you can't use the find/replace functionality to replace the style of a cell that contains a certain text. But you could achieve the same result by using **conditional formatting**:

To apply a style conditionally depending on the the content of a cell range, just do the following:

1. Select the range of cells;
2. Open Menu "`Format`" -> "`Conditional Formatting...`"
3. In the following dialogue,  select "`Formula is`" from the first ComboBox;
4. Enter the following formula into the text field:

   > `SEARCH("searchtext"; A1)`

   (assuming the ***first cell of the cell range*** [Step 1] is `A1`, and you want to highlight cells containing "searchtext")

That's it. The following screenscot shows the solution applying a custom style to all cells containing the string "ue" in the cell range `A1:A22`:

[image: Conditional formatting]

Take care about the cell reference in the formula. It should b relative to the first selected cell (in my example: A1). LibreOffice adapts the cell reference for all other cells in the selected range.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add this answer to FAQ of Libre/OpenOffice or send to its developers?